# PHP Get Selected Option if Option value "Less then equal to (<=)" operator Matches with database "Less Then Equal to (<=)" operator

Tags: php, html, opencart

How to get selected option if the option value contains operators to be compared? Such as less than equal operator, is equal to, less than equal operator. Then that option should be selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="system_process" >
    <option value="="<?php echo ($system_process === '=' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Equal To</option>
    <option value="!="<?php echo ($system_process === '!=' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Not Equal To</option>
    <option value=">="<?php echo ($system_process === '>=' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Greater Than Equal To</option>
    <option value="<="<?php echo ($system_process === '<=' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>>Less Than Equal to</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Generally for something like this I'd use a code to represent the values, rather than passing the values themselves. They make the code more difficult to read than necessary, and if you have control of both ends, there's no reason you could just use 0, 1, 2 and 3 as your values. I might have misunderstood the question, though - can you provide a bit more detail on what the problem is exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're asking. What's your actual issue? And what does the above code have to do with databases? Please provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: _“How to get selected option”_ - same way as always. _“if option value contain”_ - it doesn’t matter what it contains, that is absolutely irrelevant to how you _access_ the value. // This rather sounds as if you did not manage to properly ask about what your _actual_ problem is. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: if From database the value is less then equal operator so the option selecte should be the third one <select class="form-control" name="system_process" >
<option value="=">Equal To</option>
<option value="!=">Not Equal To</option>
<option value=">=" selected="selected">Greater Than Equal To</option>
<option value="<=">Less Than Equal to</option> 
   </select>

Comment: Reformatted code, fixed grammar.